# How do I jquery animate vertical fly-in on a layout of relative divs

Tags: jquery, css

I have a gallery I'm building and I can't get the relative divs to fly in vertically,
[See jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/unknown601/wL6rLsmq/25/) 
 I also want to add easing to my code but the standard way does not work, it seems to stop count += interval; from running?

I am trying to make it fly-in [like this.](http://www.jam3.com/work/)

```
 /*Fly in*/
  $(document).ready(function () {
      var count = 400;
      var interval = 40
      $(".gallery").each(function () {
          $(this).delay(count).animate({
              marginLeft: 0,
          }, 500);
          count += interval;
      });
  });
  /*Fly in End*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have redone it using margins to animate it and added easing using css3 because its smoother.

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/unknown601/wL6rLsmq/27/)

```
    /*Fly in*/
  $(document).ready(function () {
       var count = 400;
    var interval = 30
    $(".gallery").each(function () {
        $(this).delay(count).animate({
marginTop:0,
}, 500 );
        count += interval;
      });
  });
  /*Fly in End*/
```

CSS

```
.gallery {
    width: 300px;
    height: 169px;
    margin-top: 800px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) 0s;
    -o-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) 0s;
    transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) 0s;
}
```